# Special Characters in unicode bytes are longer than iso bytes?

Tags: ios, unicode, utf-8, nsstring, iso

Are Unicode bytes longer than ISO bytes?

If yes, I am trying to convert Objective-C `NSString` to `const Char UTF8` using `[NSString UTF8String]`. I am having an issue with Special `char bytes`. How can I solve this issue?

I am using an API for TTS(Text to speech and highlighting). API developer told me that Text highlighting is calculating on the base of bytes and this is only happening with some Special Characters. So i need to change the string from ISO to Unicode.

Thank you!

Comment: Please read [this](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

Comment: A byte is 8 bits on any system you're likely to see. And there's no such thing as a unicode byte. As for your second question, "having issue" is the worst description possible. What are you trying to do, and what problem are you having?

Answer (score 0):

Rephrasing the first question: Are unicode characters composed of more bytes than ISO characters?

Answer: They can be, it depends on the characters and the encoding method.

For the second question, provide the code you have tell us what you expect and what is actually happening that is incorrect.

Comment: Hello Zaph thank you for you Answer, Yes that what i have asked that unicode characters composed more bytes than ISO characters. I have updated my Question please have a look.